# Remove item from list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working all day on one of my first javascripts which is designed to have a user insert items into a text box using a field and submit button. Items that are put in the list have a remove button next to them.

I was wondering if anyone had any smart ideas about how I could remove items using the remove link next to the list. When this link is clicked I want to have it removed from the list but I can't really see a clean and simple way of doing it.

Demo Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/ZTuDJ/46/

```
// If JS enabled, disable main input
$("#responsibilities").prop('disabled', true);
// $("#responsibilities").addClass("hidden");

// If JS enabled then add fields
$("#resp").append('<input placeholder="Add responsibility" id="resp_input" ></input><input type="button" value="Add" id="add"> ');

// Add items to input field
var eachline='';
$("#add").click(function(){
    var lines = $('#resp_input').val().split('\n');
    var lines2 = $('#responsibilities').val().split('\n');
    if(lines2.length>10)return false;
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        if(lines[i]!='' && i+lines2.length<11){
        eachline += lines[i] + '\n';
        }    
    }

    $('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text()).before("<li>"+$("<p>"+lines+"</p>").text()+"<span class='right'><a href='#'>Remove</a></span></li>");

    $('#resp_input').val('');
});
```

I know people have much more experience, so if anyone is willing to give me any help or advice on how this could be achieved I would really apprecaite it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really simple :

```
$(document).on('click', '.right a', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/47/

To remove the textarea too, use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.right a', function(){
    var el = $(this).closest('li')
    var index = $('li').index(el);
    var text = eachline.split('\n');
    text.splice(index, 1);
    eachline = text.join('\n')
    $('#responsibilities').text(eachline)
    el.remove()
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/50/

Comment: Karl I'm sorry to be picky but could you tell me how to remove it from the text area too? It only removes it form the list but keeps it in the text area when ideally these should be synced

Comment: @JamesWillson Edited my answer, take a look

Comment: Note that you should add class to your li and use it when doing `$('li').index(el)`, else, if there is other `li` in the page, it will no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
$("ul li a").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/SdpFf/)